# What is the difference between Vert/Verts and Vertex/Vertices?

Tags: differences, terminology, mathematics, programming, computing

What is the difference between Vert/Verts and Vertex/Vertices?

Both forms seem to be used interchangeably in mathematics and computer graphics.

Blender (3D software) uses Vert/Verts in it's User Interface, but also Vertex/Vertices in it's user documentation.

Answer (score 3):

For a point in a graph (or model), the singular form is ["*vertex*"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vertex) and the plural is "*vertices*". The plural "*vertexes*" is also sometimes used.

> a point (as of an angle, polygon, polyhedron, graph, or network) that terminates a line or curve or comprises the intersection of two or more lines or curves.

Vert/Verts is likely an abbreviation, slang or domain specific terminology. They don't appear in a dictionary with the same meaning as vertex/vertices (only as "*vertical*" and heraldry concepts).

Comment: This is just my supposition, but it seems obvious that "vert" and "verts" are abbreviated versions of "vertex" and "vertices", making a commonly-used word and its plural form shorter and faster to use.

Comment: Or maybe a programmer in the project was using a term from their native language.  (I'm not sure if there is a language that uses "vert" -- I'm just brainstorming.)